# Parsing JSON in jQuery into div tag

Tags: jquery, json

I have the following JSON:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","FIRSTNAME"],"DATA":[[1,"Steve"],[2,"Jim"],[3,"Bill"],[4,"Tony"]]}
```

I am trying to write some jQuery that parses this and puts the values of the first names into a div tag.

I cannot seem to get the syntax right.

Any help would this would be great.

Thanks!

UPDATE:

I am now able to parse the JSON thanks @jayendra

I am now trying to build it into the rest of my jQuery. I am trying this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "getQ.cfc?method=getUsers",
            success:function(data) {

                $(data.DATA).each(function(index, value){
                   console.log(value[1]);
                });

          },

        });     

    });
```

It is just not returning anything to the console but if I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "getQ.cfc?method=getUsers",
            success:function(data) {

            console.log(data);


          },

        });     

    });
```

It returns the JSON into the console like above like this:

```
{"COLUMNS":["ID","FIRSTNAME"],"DATA":[[1,"Steve"],[2,"Jim"],[3,"Bill"],[4,"Tony"]]}
```

Any help on this and why I am not getting anything in the console when I loop would be great.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example -

```
var data = {"COLUMNS":["ID","FIRSTNAME"],"DATA":[[1,"Steve"],[2,"Jim"],[3,"Bill"],[4,"Tony"]]}

$(data.DATA).each(function(index, value){
    console.log(value[1]);
})
```

Comment: This works great. Thanks @Jayendra. If you have a minute I updated my question. If you could help with that it would be awesome. Thanks!

Comment: Can you try adding dataType: "json" to your ajax call.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
var index = json.COLUMNS.indexOf('FIRSTNAME');
var len = json.DATA.length
for(var i=0; i<len;i++)
   alert(json.DATA[i][index]);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/HQBrw/20/)**

Comment: you may want to do json.COLUMNS.indexOf('FIRSTNAME') instead of hardcoding it to be the element at index 1